# Get Values without the lowest 3 dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having trouble to ignore values from the lowest 3 dates.
I have a table like this:

```
ValueKey|FromProduct |Customer |Value|Date
1x200x30|Coffemkr3000|M.Smith  |1000 |2019-12-31
1x200x30|Coffemkr3000|M.Smith  |2000 |2020-01-31
1x200x30|Coffemkr3000|M.Smith  |3000 |2020-02-29
1x200x30|Coffemkr3000|M.Smith  |4000 |2020-03-31
1x200x30|Coffemkr3000|M.Smith  |5000 |2020-04-30
1x200x30|Coffemkr3000|A.Guerra |10   |2019-12-31
1x200x30|Coffemkr3000|A.Guerra |20   |2020-01-31
1x200x30|Coffemkr3000|A.Guerra |30   |2020-02-29
1x200x30|Coffemkr3000|A.Guerra |40   |2020-03-31
1x200x30|Coffemkr3000|A.Guerra |50   |2020-04-30
Zx999x50|CapsuleR9999|M.Smith  |1000 |2019-12-31
Zx999x50|CapsuleR9999|M.Smith  |2000 |2020-01-31
Zx999x50|CapsuleR9999|M.Smith  |3000 |2020-02-29
Zx999x50|CapsuleR9999|M.Smith  |4000 |2020-03-31
Zx999x50|CapsuleR9999|M.Smith  |5000 |2020-04-30
Zx999x50|CapsuleR9999|A.Guerra |10   |2019-12-31
Zx999x50|CapsuleR9999|A.Guerra |20   |2020-01-31
Zx999x50|CapsuleR9999|A.Guerra |30   |2020-02-29
Zx999x50|CapsuleR9999|A.Guerra |40   |2020-03-31
Zx999x50|CapsuleR9999|A.Guerra |50   |2020-04-30
```

And I need to do some calculations with these values:

```
ValueKey|FromProduct |Customer |Value|Date
1x200x30|Coffemkr3000|M.Smith  |4000 |2020-03-31
1x200x30|Coffemkr3000|M.Smith  |5000 |2020-04-30
1x200x30|Coffemkr3000|A.Guerra |40   |2020-03-31
1x200x30|Coffemkr3000|A.Guerra |50   |2020-04-30
Zx999x50|CapsuleR9999|M.Smith  |4000 |2020-03-31
Zx999x50|CapsuleR9999|M.Smith  |5000 |2020-04-30
Zx999x50|CapsuleR9999|A.Guerra |40   |2020-03-31
Zx999x50|CapsuleR9999|A.Guerra |50   |2020-04-30
```

So my problem here is, I need to ignore the lowest 3 dates of each `ValueKey - FromProduct - Customer` combination.

Is there an elegant way to do this in one statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `DENSE_RANK()` to get the rank of each row within a result set partition defined by `ValueKey`, `FromProduct` and `Customer` columns. `DENSE_RANK()` is important if you have multiple rows with a same date for each `ValueKey`, `FromProduct` and `Customer`. If that is not important, using `ROW_NUMBER()` is also an option, but in this case the rows will be numbered sequentially and only the first 3 rows for each `ValueKey`, `FromProduct` and `Customer` combinations will be ignored.

Table (I assume, that `Date` column has `date` data type):

```
CREATE TABLE Yourtable (
    ValueKey varchar(8),
    FromProduct varchar(100),
    Customer varchar(100), 
    [Value] int, 
    [Date] date
);
INSERT INTO Yourtable 
    (ValueKey, FromProduct, Customer, [Value], [Date])
VALUES
    ('1x200x30', 'Coffemkr3000', 'M.Smith',  1000, '20191231'),
    ('1x200x30', 'Coffemkr3000', 'M.Smith',  2000, '20200131'),
    ('1x200x30', 'Coffemkr3000', 'M.Smith',  3000, '20200229'),
    ('1x200x30', 'Coffemkr3000', 'M.Smith',  4000, '20200331'),
    ('1x200x30', 'Coffemkr3000', 'M.Smith',  5000, '20200430'),
    ('1x200x30', 'Coffemkr3000', 'A.Guerra', 10,   '20191231'),
    ('1x200x30', 'Coffemkr3000', 'A.Guerra', 20,   '20200131'),
    ('1x200x30', 'Coffemkr3000', 'A.Guerra', 30,   '20200229'),
    ('1x200x30', 'Coffemkr3000', 'A.Guerra', 40,   '20200331'),
    ('1x200x30', 'Coffemkr3000', 'A.Guerra', 50,   '20200430'),
    ('Zx999x50', 'CapsuleR9999', 'M.Smith',  1000, '20191231'),
    ('Zx999x50', 'CapsuleR9999', 'M.Smith',  2000, '20200131'),
    ('Zx999x50', 'CapsuleR9999', 'M.Smith',  3000, '20200229'),
    ('Zx999x50', 'CapsuleR9999', 'M.Smith',  4000, '20200331'),
    ('Zx999x50', 'CapsuleR9999', 'M.Smith',  5000, '20200430'),
    ('Zx999x50', 'CapsuleR9999', 'A.Guerra', 10,   '20191231'),
    ('Zx999x50', 'CapsuleR9999', 'A.Guerra', 20,   '20200131'),
    ('Zx999x50', 'CapsuleR9999', 'A.Guerra', 30,   '20200229'),
    ('Zx999x50', 'CapsuleR9999', 'A.Guerra', 40,   '20200331'),
    ('Zx999x50', 'CapsuleR9999', 'A.Guerra', 50,   '20200430');
```

Statement:

```
SELECT ValueKey, FromProduct, Customer, [Value], [Date]
FROM
(
   SELECT 
      *,
      DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ValueKey, FromProduct, Customer ORDER BY [Date]) AS RN
   FROM YourTable
) t
WHERE t.RN > 3
```

Result:

```
ValueKey    FromProduct     Customer    Value   Date
1x200x30    Coffemkr3000    A.Guerra    40      2020-03-31
1x200x30    Coffemkr3000    A.Guerra    50      2020-04-30
1x200x30    Coffemkr3000    M.Smith     4000    2020-03-31
1x200x30    Coffemkr3000    M.Smith     5000    2020-04-30
Zx999x50    CapsuleR9999    A.Guerra    40      2020-03-31
Zx999x50    CapsuleR9999    A.Guerra    50      2020-04-30
Zx999x50    CapsuleR9999    M.Smith     4000    2020-03-31
Zx999x50    CapsuleR9999    M.Smith     5000    2020-04-30
```

Comment: Wow- Thank you for this function! Works like a charm in all of my tests i did! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following with `row_number()`. here is the [**demo**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7sNc3Bt5hA8FzgMH4GbXoY/1).

```
select
    ValueKey,
    FromProduct,
    Customer,
    Value,
    Date
from
(
    select
        *,
        row_number() over (partition by ValueKey, Customer, FromProduct order by Date) as rnk
    from yourTable

)  val

where rnk > 3
```

Output:

```
*------------------------------------------------------*
|valuekey   fromproduct     customer  value    date    |
*------------------------------------------------------*
|Zx999x50   CapsuleR9999    A.Guerra    40   2020-03-31|
|Zx999x50   CapsuleR9999    A.Guerra    50   2020-04-30|
|1x200x30   Coffemkr3000    M.Smith    4000  2020-03-31|
|1x200x30   Coffemkr3000    M.Smith    5000  2020-04-30|
|1x200x30   Coffemkr3000    A.Guerra    40   2020-03-31|
|1x200x30   Coffemkr3000    A.Guerra    50   2020-04-30|
|Zx999x50   CapsuleR9999    M.Smith    4000  2020-03-31|
|Zx999x50   CapsuleR9999    M.Smith    5000  2020-04-30|
*------------------------------------------------------*
```